# Not sure what app is serving HTTP Port 80 on my linux machine?

Tags: linux, port

I've run `netstat -ano` and `netstat -lnp` and neither outputs any process listening on Port 80.

I have a node.js app that is set to listen to port 8001, and I'm suppose to have Nginx proxy-forward certain requests to my node app.

I do see my node app listening on port 8001.

As far as I can tell, it's the node app that is serving all http requests, as I've stopped nginx.

I've also run `iptables --list` and nothing showed up.

So, how is it possible that my app running on port 8001, is serving requests in from port 80? Or rather, what other configuration stuff shoudl I be looking at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the face of it what you are describing is not possible...

If `lsof -i :80` says there is nothing listening on port 80 and `iptables -t nat -L` and `iptables -t mangle -L` say there are no iptables rules redirecting traffic from port 80 to port 8001 then there should be no way that an application listening on port 8001 can see requests on port 80.

So if you have ruled out all that you need to consider whether something outside the system, such as an external firewall, is rewriting the traffic.

The best way to find out would be to monitor the network traffic with `tcpdump -i any port 80 or port 8001` and see what port the traffic seems to be appearing on.

Comment: BOOM. Okay, so why does iptables --list not show the PREROUTING policy? I used `iptables -t nat -L` and it showed me the redirect that was happening.

Next followup: How do I clear that out?

Comment: It's not showing it because by default `iptables` acts on the `filter` table and the `PREROUTING` chain is in the `nat` table, so you need to add `-t nat` to see it.

Comment: Cool! i backed up my iptables then used -D PREROUTING 1 -t nat to baleete the rule. Thank so much, I was really scratching my head with this one!